# PGF-UMLCd: How to remove Attribute-section

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlcd

I need a uml class-diagram and I am using pgf-umlcd.
My "Classes" do not have attributes (because it is a C-Interface). 
But the attibute section is still drawn and i could not find an option to remove it .

My classes look like this :

```
______________________
|                    |
| class name         |
|--------------------|
|--------------------|
|                    |
| some functions.... |
| more functions.....|
|...                 |
---------------------
```

I'd like to remove the attribute-section:

```
______________________
|                    |
| class name         |
|--------------------|                 
| some functions.... |
| more functions.....|
|...                 |
----------------------
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}[text width=7cm]{test}{0,0}
    \operation{execute(cmd : command) : abct}
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please help me :D I couldn't find anything in the documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's basically the first thing that's said in the documentation:

> Note: If you don’t want to show empty parts in the diagrams, please use `simplified` option, e.g. `\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}[text width=7cm]{test}{0,0}
    \operation{execute(cmd : command) : abct}
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```